# How to add lines in top and bottom of the file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code in my python script and I need to add some logic there to add some lines on the top of the file and add some lines at the bottom of the file.The name of the file will pass as a parameter and that file is having a HTML code.Could you please help me how could I add the line at the top of the file and bottom of the file

I pass the parameter to my script in below way

```
abc.py -u abcde -p ***** -t "append line top and bottom" -f "test.txt"
```

Below is the piece where I want to add the logic to add line at top and bottom of the file

```
else:

        with open(options.file, 'r') as fd:
            html = fd.read()
```

I want to add below line at the top of the existing file test.txt

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">
<ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[
```

and want to add the below lines at the bottom of the file test.txt

```
]]></ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

test.txt file is having lots of HTML code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Briefly, what have you tried, and how did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file in `r+` mode, read its contents, rewind it, write the 'prefix' part, write the contents and then write the suffix part. Something like:

```
# obtain these from wherever you want:
prefix = "<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"html\">\n<ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA["
suffix = "]]></ac:plain-text-body>\n</ac:structured-macro>"

with open("test.txt", 'r+') as f:
    contents = f.read()  # cache the full file content
    f.seek(0)  # rewind
    f.write(prefix)  # write the prefix
    f.write(contents)  # write the cached content
    f.write(suffix)  # write the suffix
    f.truncate()  # truncate the rest in case we decided to play with the 'contents' length
```

Of course, this will read the whole file in RAM but unless you have gigigabytes long HTML/XML files (in which case I wonder what parser could process them) this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For adding at the end, you can use

`with open(options.file, 'a') as fd: # it is important to open as 'a' to append
     html = fd.write("What you want to write to file")`

To add at top you could read the file into a variable as string, and then append the file to the text to write at top, and follow by writing the whole thing to file

But this would use a lot of RAM, and would only work for small files